# Missing folder '/etc/pki/trust/anchors'?

Tags: tls, openssl, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create an ssl certificate via openssl, through my virtual machine at google cloud. But one of the last steps is to copy my ca.crt from my root, to the'/etc/pki/trust/anchors' folder.

This folder does not exist on my Linux computer can someone help me with this.

[image]

Comment: It's not difficult to find, if it exists... `find / -type d -name anchors`. I would guess though that Google does not give you access.

Comment: I will try, thank you